# Can these queries be combined into one using a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

One query finds the aggregates the subtotals by country:

```
SELECT
    customer.country,
    SUM(i.subtotal) AS total
FROM
    invoices i
    LEFT JOIN customer ON i.customer_id = customer.id
WHERE
    status = 'Paid'
    AND datepaid BETWEEN '2020-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-06-01 00:00:00'
    AND customer.billing_day <> 0
    AND customer.register_date < '2020-06-01 00:00:00'
    AND customer.account_exempt = 'f'
    customer.country <> ''
GROUP BY
    customer.country;
```

The other query aggregates the subtotals for US customers by state:

```
SELECT
    customer.state,
    SUM(i.subtotal) AS total
FROM
    invoices i
    LEFT JOIN customer ON i.customer_id = customer.id
WHERE
    status = 'Paid'
    AND datepaid BETWEEN '2020-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-06-01 00:00:00'
    AND customer.billing_day <> 0
    AND customer.register_date < '2020-06-01 00:00:00'
    AND customer.account_exempt = 'f'
    AND customer.country = 'US'
    AND customer.state <> ''
GROUP BY
    customer.state;
```

Is it possible to write one query that returns each country's total, and if the country is the US, also returns the state's total? I have read that subqueries can be used to combine two aggregate functions, but I'm not sure how that would be done here.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: what is the purpose of combining them? They are in different levels (one has country level data, other has state level data). You can combine but it will create more confusion.

Comment: Note : `AND customer.billing_day ...` in the WHERE clause will degrade your LEFT join to a plain join.

Comment: @wildplasser Do all of the conditions relating to the customer table in the WHERE clause degrade the LEFT join? Thank you for pointing this out, I'm a newbie.

Comment: Yes. By inferring on `customer.some_field = 'some_value'` you implicitely force some_field to be NOT NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two keys in the `group by`:

```
SELECT c.country,
       (CASE WHEN c.country = 'US' THEN c.state END) as state,
       SUM(i.subtotal) AS total
FROM invoices i JOIN
     customer c
     ON i.customer_id = c.id
WHERE i.status = 'Paid' AND
      i.datepaid >= '2020-05-01' AND
      i.datepaid < '2020-06-01' AND
      c.billing_day <> 0 AND
      c.register_date < '2020-06-01' AND
      c.account_exempt = 'f'
      c.country <> ''
GROUP BY c.country, (CASE WHEN c.country = 'US' THEN c.state END);
```

Note the other changes to the query:

- Your `WHERE` clause turns the outer join into an inner join, so `LEFT JOIN` is misleading.
- All column references are qualified.
- Presumably, you want dates in May, so I adjusted the logic.
- There is no need to include times when working only with dates.